# im having textarea in html when i click the button i need to save the content inside the textarea as pdf file. how can i do it?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML code. I need to save the content as pdf, whatever I'm giving in the text area. By this code I'm facing two problems.

1. I can save the pdf, but there is no content inside the textarea
2. When I click the as pdf it downloading only once, not again.

Please help me to solve this issue

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>file</title>
 </head>
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
 </script>
 <body id="target">
 <p> reason:</p>
 <div>
 <textarea id="content" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div id="editor"></div>
 <button  id="cmd" onclick="save()">as pdf</button>
  script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
  var doc= new jsPDF();
  var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
   return true;
   }
   };
   $('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML(
   $('#content').html(), 15, 15, 
   { 'width': 170, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers });
   doc.save('Reason.pdf'); 
    } );
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below

```
 <html>
     <head>
     <title>file</title>
     </head>
     <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
     </script>
     <body id="target">
     <p> reason:</p>
     <div>
     <textarea id="content" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div id="editor"></div>
     <button  id="cmd">as pdf</button>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js">
      </script>
      <script>
      var doc= new jsPDF();
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
          doc.text($('#content').val(), 10, 10);
          doc.save('Reason.pdf'); 
        });
       </script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: thanks  paisley working fine :)..what to do if i need to save the textarea content as docx and excel. #paisley.london